# more elegant way when call parent method with the same name

Tags: python

My subclass extends the `Formatter` class,
I wonder know is there any elegant way, to rewrite my code

### Parent

```
class Formatter(object):
    def resp_in_hash(self, resp):
        ...
        return rtn_hash
```

### Child

```
from formatter import Formatter
# -----------------------------------------------------------------
class Request(Formatter):

    def req(self, url_path, is_no_cache=True):
        ...
    def resp_in_hash(self, url_path):
        resp, content = self.req(url_path)
        return super(Request, self).resp_in_hash(content)
```

Comment: That looks like an inappropriate application of inheritance, but I can't really tell since you've posted so little code.

Answer (score 2):

Two ways to rewrite it:

When you know which version of the method you want to call you can name it directly, but in that case need to pass self as an argument:

```
    return Formatter.resp_in_hash(self, content)
```

Not necessarily more elegant.

---

Python 3 introduced a new cleaner `super` format for the common case when you want to step up from the current class and pass `self` (the first argument):

```
    return super().resp_in_hash(content)
```

This only works in python 3, though.

Comment: Note that calling `Formatter` is not necessarily equivalent to `super`, if the classes become part of a more complex hierarchy. See [Python’s super() considered super!](http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/)